# Efficiency questions in a closed loop expander

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

So let's say I have a condenser, and both the inlet and outlet are connected to a pressure vessel that has hot gas fluid. Let's say there is a pneumatic pump creating a load on the connection to the top of the condenser, and there is a straight pipe connecting the bottom of the pressure vessel to the pressure vessel

[image]

Would the pneumatic pump do work as the fluid condenses?
The problem is that the pressure vessel is creating equal pressure, lets say 30 psi, to both of the condenser's connections. There is no reason for flow to happen in the system.

I suppose as the condensate is created everywhere in the condenser, because of gravity it would drain down the condenser, and it would probably create more surface area at the top for new gas to condensate, while new gas cant be condensing at the bottom because the walls are wet with condensate already, and if the top half of the condenser is has less travel area from the pressure vessel, then the fluid would flow from the pressure vessel through the pump, to the top of the condenser. Could also increase the length of the bottom condenser tube, this would also encourage draining by the bottom tube and flow by the top tube.

But the real question/problem is, if there is lots of pressure, coming from both pressure vessel outlets, that would probably limit the maximum pressure delta, and also limit how much work the pump could even do.

i suppose it might be possible to use some kind pump to pump condensate into the pressure vessel, so that a great pressure difference can exist and to extract lots of work from the pump, but that doesn't sound too efficient. Might be possible to use some kind of gearing to make the bottom pump, move 1 cubic inch of liquid per 600 cubic inches of gas that were pushed out of the top. It probably wouldn't create too much loss especially if both pumps have their shafts linked by gears. It would be a type of turbo.

What do you think? is this possible? is there an easier way?

Comment: Are you sure you have that pump in the right place?

Comment: where would be the right place?

Comment: I think it would be in the lower tube.

Comment: wouldnt the weight of all the falling condensate work against the flow?  although i guess you could probably make the condensate fall out the other pipe and it would probably boost the flow